# Where is my database hosted?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, database

Surprisingly, I've been able to develop quite a few web apps without knowing the answer to this fundamental question:

**When I construct a website that uses a database, is that database stored within my hosting provider's infrastructure?**

I understand that this may differ between situations (database type, hosting provider, ect). So, for example, **in my Meteor app, is my MongoDB (or Meteor.Collection) stored within Meteor's infrastructure, or remotely somewhere in Mongo's?**

Thanks!

Comment: This is really “where does Meteor store the database?” Which of course only they can answer. Presumably its on one of their servers, but there are dedicated MongoDB “DBaaS” providers.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `meteor deploy` your database is hosted externally via MongoHQ (see http://weusethat.com/meteor/) that ends up on Amazon's EC2 cloud.

If you use `meteor run` it's hosted on the same machine you use `meteor run` with (which makes it easy for development but not that great for production).

If you use `meteor bundle` to make your own meteor bundle you need to run your own mongodb database somewhere and link it up with your meteor instance with the `MONGO_URL` environment variable. See the `README` file in your tgz bundle'd app for a bit more on this.

So you can make it whichever way you want really. It can work on your own hosting provider or an external one with the bundled app too (such as MongoHQ).

Answer (score 0):

Typically a database would be behind the hosting provider's firewall and part of their infrastructure. This is the common way to do it for security/performance reasons. However, there are no technical limitations that prevents the database from being hosted somewhere entirely different. It's all about permissions, so it's possible to host your site with one provider and the database with another provider.